# spawning a command prompt in a different process and sending/receiving commands on Windows

Tags: ruby

I have a problem at hand which requires me to spawn a command prompt as a different process and send some commands to it and capture/parse the command output. This interaction needs to be in the form of a parent-child process where say all the commands can be put in a ruby file and upon running the ruby file, the commands are sent to the console(command prompt) and output is received from it and processed in the ruby script.

The general logic which I would follow is:

1. Spawn a different process by using a fork and get a process id
2. Obtain streams for the process
3. Write to the input stream of the process and read from the output stream.

The environment which I am using is Windows XP machine with Ruby 1.9.2 installed on it. I downloaded the win32-process library found over [here](http://win32utils.rubyforge.org/). By using that library, I could do step 1 as follows

```
require 'win32/process'
    APP_NAME = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
    process_info = Process.create(:app_name => APP_NAME,
      :creation_flags => Windows::Process::CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
      :process_inherit  => false,
      :thread_inherit   => true,
      :cwd => "C:\\"
    )
```

Since the win32-process library is based on using processes and threads on windows, I tried to go through the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) help for it. While reading the [Creation of a Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article, I found that the GetStdHandle method could be used to get the handles to the input and output streams. But, i could not find this method implemented anywhere in win32-process.

Can someone provide me with some guidance on how to proceed with steps 2 and 3?

Also, is there any other way which can be used to solve the problem at hand?

Also, I would like to learn more about inter-process communication or in general spawning and forking of processes, so can somebody please tell me some good references where I could study them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you just use `system()` or backticks to run your commands?

Comment: I think system() does not return a handle

Comment: Ok, what about `IO.popen`? Example: `IO.popen('dir').readlines`.

Comment: Haven't tried that approach out since I did not know about it. Will look into it? Would i need a library for popen on windows since I see a library like win32-open3 on this page http://rubyforge.org/projects/win32utils

Comment: `IO.popen` is part of the std library, so it's included on windows by default. I don't have experience with win32-open3, but it might be worth to take a look at that too.

Comment: @Casper thanks I'll look into it and check whether it solves the problem at hand

Comment: @Casper I tried using IO.popen("C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe") and it did not spawn a new console. Should I be using a combination of the code posted in the question and IO.popen

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12173/discussion-between-casper-and-chaitanya)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example using IO.popen in windows, imo if it works with the stdlib don't use gems

```
IO.popen("other_program", "w+") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts "here, have some input"
  pipe.close_write  # If other_program process doesn't flush its output, you probably need to use this to send an end-of-file, which tells other_program to give us its output. If you don't do this, the program may hang/block, because other_program is waiting for more input.
  output = pipe.read
end

# You can also use the return value from your block. (exit code stored in $? as usual)
output = IO.popen("other_program", "w+") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts "here, have some input"
  pipe.close_write
  pipe.read
end
```

Comment: if you want to discover other methods read this excellent blog http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/

Comment: Thanks peter and Casper for the links and your help